# Remove padding between 2 jquery tab

Tags: jquery, css, tabs

I have one Jquery UI Tab and i show another Jquery tab on click of first selection. I dont want to show any spacing between these 2 element. Right now when i click on **menu Item 1**, it shows another tab which has little gap between parent tab and child tab .it shows thin line between the tabs, How can i remove that. 
Here is Fiddle [Link](http://jsfiddle.net/Pctm4/43/)

I tried this `$("div.ui-tabs-panel").css('padding','0px');` but no help.

Any help in this regard would be highly appreciated.

I mean this Space
[image]

Comment: What browser are you using? It looks fine to me, it applies the padding 0px to the tabs-panel divs?

Comment: I use Chrome, Safari, it does not work on any of them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to edit the css of the subtabs

```
#subtabs-buttons {padding-top : 0px; padding-left : 0px;}
```

[have updated your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Pctm4/46/)

Answer (score 1):

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Pctm4/47/)

```
$(function () {
    $("#tabs-buttons").tabs();
    $("#subtabs-buttons").tabs();
    $("div.ui-tabs-panel").css('margin', '0px');
    $('#tabs-1').css('padding', '0');
    $('#tabs-1 div').css('padding-top', '0');
});
```

or

CSS

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Pctm4/48/)

```
#tabs-1{
    padding:0;
}
#tabs-1 div{
    padding-top:0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**If you mean the second tab (inside tabs) then:**

```
#subtabs-buttons ul{padding: 0}
#subtabs-buttons li {margin: 0}
```

Comment: YEs you needed padding-left on parent...you got your answer

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to accomplish something like this?

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Pctm4/44/)

I used **CSS**:

```
#subtabs-buttons{
    padding:0;
}
```

I'm not shure this is what you're looking for.

You can also add a padding between the subtabs text and the border by using this code:

```
#stabs-1 p {
    padding: 5px;
}
```